# perf-like assembly reading tool

Tags: perf, assembly

`perf` has a very friendly terminal interface for performance analysis. It has a very helpful feature that the branch target is annotated with beautiful arrows, showing where this branch is going to (if taken, anyway).
This is not possible if I read the disassembly code generated by `objdump`. Is there any other tool doing exactly the same thing of `perf`, without actually `perf`ing the program?

Comment: The standard disassembler these days is [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/).  But it isn't really affordable if you plan to use it non-commercially.